# Ubuntu 18.04 and dolphin file manager's terminal did not work

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, dolphin

I using ubuntu 18.04 and i am so like kubuntu's dolphin file manager so i installed via apt-get and its working but i tried but dolphin terminal did not work what can be it ?

its changing terminal location but terminal not show

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT97L.png)

Comment: Do you have the Konsole installed ? Bug 371822 - Dolphin should not toggle the terminal panel if Konsole is not installed: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371822

Comment: nice i did not know dolphin working via konsole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use Dolpin via terminal install the dolphin and konsole . konsole is different program but working together

```
   $ sudo apt-get install dolphin konsole
```